# How to align items inside a QVBoxLayout without overlapping them

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following List View `customitemdelegate` where I am trying to list two `QHBoxLayout` inside a `QVBoxLayout` but the second `QHBoxLayout` gets hidden below the first `QHBoxLayout`. How can I adjust the code to make the `QVBoxLayout` autogrow to accommodate the children `QHBoxLayout` without them overlapping ?

```
#include "customitemdelegate.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

CustomItemDelegate::CustomItemDelegate(QObject *parent)
    : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

void CustomItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const {
    // Ensure the item is valid and visible
    if (!index.isValid() || !option.rect.isValid())
        return;

    // Set up the style options
    QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;
    initStyleOption(&opt, index);

    // Set the background color for the item based on its state
    if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected) {
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, QColor("#DDDDDD"));
    } else {
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, QColor("#F7F7F7"));
    }

    // Create a QWidget to render the item
    QWidget *itemWidget = new QWidget;

    // Create a QVBoxLayout for the item layout
    QVBoxLayout *itemContainer = new QVBoxLayout(itemWidget); // Use itemWidget as the parent for itemLayout

    // Set the background color for the item based on its state
    if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected) {
        itemWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: #DDDDDD;");
    } else {
        itemWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: #FFFFFF;");
    }

    // Get the data for the item
    QPixmap icon = index.data(Qt::DecorationRole).value<QPixmap>();
    QString text = index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    QString additionalText = "Additional Text " + text; // Replace with your additional text

    // Create a QHBoxLayout for the icon and text
    QHBoxLayout *iconTextWrapper = new QHBoxLayout;

    // Create a QLabel for the text
    QLabel *textLabel = new QLabel(text);
    textLabel->setStyleSheet("font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #333333; font-weight: bold; font-size: 8px; padding: 3px 12px; margin-left: 0");

    // Create a QLabel for the icon
    if (!icon.isNull()) {
        QLabel *iconLabel = new QLabel();
        iconLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter); // Center the icon within the label
        iconLabel->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid #D7FAC3;");
        iconLabel->setFixedWidth(72);
        iconLabel->setFixedHeight(32);
        iconLabel->setPixmap(icon);

        iconTextWrapper->addWidget(iconLabel); // Add the icon label to the layout
    }

    iconTextWrapper->addWidget(textLabel); // Add the text label to the layout

    // Create a QLabel for the additional text
    QLabel *additionalTextLabel = new QLabel(additionalText);
    additionalTextLabel->setStyleSheet("font-family: Arial, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 8px; padding: 3px 12px; margin-left: 0");

    QHBoxLayout *revFooterWrapper = new QHBoxLayout(itemWidget);
    revFooterWrapper->addWidget(additionalTextLabel);

    // Add the icon and text layout and additional text to the item layout
    itemContainer->addLayout(iconTextWrapper);
    itemContainer->addLayout(revFooterWrapper);

    // Set the size constraint for the itemWidget to automatically grow
    itemWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

    // Ensure the layout stretches vertically
    itemContainer->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop);

    // Render the item widget onto the view
    itemWidget->render(painter, option.rect.topLeft(), QRegion(), QWidget::RenderFlag::DrawChildren);
}
```

Comment: As it is not really a program that you posted we can not check ... but perhaps qt does not expect you to compose widgets hierarchy when you are supposed to paint something.

Comment: You're passing the same widget `itemWidget` as the parent of both the `QVBoxLayout` *and* the second `QHBoxLayout` -- the end result being that the widget only uses the `QHBoxLayout` and both the `QVBoxLayout` and the first `QHBoxLayout` are lost (and probably leaked).